# Cannot sign with ecdsa module in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, sign, ecdsa

I am trying to use the ecdsa module to sign some data with a crypto ecdh private key. My code is below:

```
shaMsg = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(myData).digest();
signed = ecdsa.sign(shaMsg, myECDHKey);
```

I am facing the following problem:

> ERROR: Server - Caught exception: Error: Expected property "1" of type BigInteger, got Buffer

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I did not receive any answer, I tried with other modules and get what I wanted with the `elliptic` module:

```
var EC = require("elliptic").ec;
var ec = new EC("secp256k1");

var shaMsg = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(myData.toString()).digest();
var mySign = ec.sign(shaMsg, privateKey, {canonical: true});
```

I hope it can help someone else.

Comment: I am getting `Error: Assertion failed` while doing this

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with:

```
var BigInteger = require('bigi');
var signature = ecdsa.sign(shaMsg, BigInteger.fromBuffer(privateKey));
```

But couldn´t verify with publicKey of type Buffer it expects Point.